# how to store a b+ tree in a file in java?

Tags: java, data-structures

How can I store a B+ tree structure in a file in Java?

After creating a B+ tree, how can I persistently store it in a file instead of using memory? Can I store every node in the file?

Comment: Not a real question. Once you've got a B+tree implemented, saving it to a file is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) and simply writing the whole object into a file.